# Laplace Transform of $sin(at)$ using Different Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am trying to understand a separate way of showing $\mathcal{L}\{sin(at)\}$ using the the following method:

What I have so far is

$$\text{Let $g(t)=f(at)$ where we substitute $u=at$. Then we have} $$
$$\mathcal{L}\{g(s)\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st} g(t)\;dt$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=\int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(at) \;dt$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=\frac{1}{a}\ \int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(u) \;du$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;= \frac{1}{a} \mathcal{L}\{f(u)\}$$
$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;= \frac{1}{a} \mathcal{L}\{f(at)\}$$

From this formula and the fact that $\mathcal{L}\{sin(t)\}=\frac{1}{1+s^2}\;$, I then solve this to be:

$$\mathcal{L}\{sin(t)\}= \frac{1}{a}\:\mathcal{L}\{sin(at)\}$$
$$therefore \;\;\mathcal{L}\{sin(at)\}=\frac{a}{1+s^2}$$

Clearly, there is an issue since $sin(at) = \frac{a}{a^2+s^2}$, so I was wondering where I might be making a mistake? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there just a little mistake..

You need to substitute also t in the exponential
$$\mathcal{L}(f(at))=\frac{1}{a}\ \int_0^\infty e^{-\color{red}{st}} f(u) \;du$$
you should have
$$\mathcal{L}(f(at))=\frac{1}{a}\ \int_0^\infty e^{-su/a} f(u) \;du=\frac 1 aF\left(\frac s a\right)$$
$$\implies \mathcal{L}(\sin(at))=\frac 1a \frac 1 {1+s^2/a^2}$$
$$\mathcal{L}(\sin(at))=\frac a {a^2+s^2}$$

Comment: Thank you, This clarified it!

Comment: you'are welcome @M.Damon